# Open default map in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I have to open link into default map app in ios? otherwise first check google map present or not ,if yes then open link into google map otherwise in default browser of ios?

Comment: Then open. No one is stopping you right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Custom URL Scheme to achieve this? As per the documentation, you can set Native app URL string to call `Maps` from your app. Something like the below:

```
-(IBAction)mapLinkTapped:(id)sender {

    NSString *mapURL = @"http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mapURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}
```

This opens the default `Maps` app on your device. If that isn't available, then this goes into a browser and opens the map.

For more info on passing parameters, please refer this [documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html).